# How to get HWND with GLFWwindow pointer?

Tags: c++, windows, glfw

I have the pointer of a GLFWwindow(It is a struct defined in glfw3.h, seems to be a openGL struct?). How can I use the pointer to get the HWND?

Comment: The link posted in the answer is the first search hit for "GLFWWindow HWND". Please do a minimum of research before posting on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLFW has a section about [native access](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__native.html) there you can find this function that allows you to retrieve the `HWND`:

[`HWND glfwGetWin32Window ( GLFWwindow * window)`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__native.html#gafe5079aa79038b0079fc09d5f0a8e667):

> **Returns**
> The HWND of the specified window, or NULL if an error occurred.
> **Thread safety**
> This function may be called from any thread. Access is not synchronized.
> **Since**
> Added in version 3.0.

Please read the documentation carefully:

> **By using the native access functions you assert that you know what you're doing and how to fix problems caused by using them. If you don't, you shouldn't be using them.**
> Before the inclusion of `glfw3native.h`, you may define zero or more window system API macro and zero or more context creation API macros.
> The chosen backends **must** match those the library was compiled for. Failure to do this will cause a link-time error.

Comment: Really appreciate. I've looked up the code of glfw for a lot of time, and did not find this code....

Comment: @ZeroZerg you should read the [docs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/modules.html) and not the code  which has the section `Native access: Functions related to accessing native handles`. Furthermore - as already mentioned by another comment - a search for `GLFWWindow HWND` leads exactly to that page.